# CHECK Constraint on Group function?

Tags: sql, constraints, exists

I need an SQL constraint (using SQLDeveloper) to check that for a specific account_id, only ONE or NO regular_id exists, such as the data attached, cell containing '6' being what should not be allowed, even though it is a different value.

```
AccountID    RegularID     OpenID
 1            5             null
 1            null          10
 1            null          11
 1            6                             <-- Forbidden
```

Answer (score 3):

Best way is with a trigger

```
  Create trigger trig_NoSingleRegId 
  On MyTable For Insert, Update
  As

        if Exists(Select * From MyTable t
                   Where AccountId In (Select AcountId From inserted)
                   Group By AccountId   
                   Having Count(Distinct regularId) > 1)     
        Begin
            RollBack Transaction
            Raiserror('Cannot have more than one RegularId per AccountId', 16, 1)
        End
```

Note: The Where clause is for performance only, to limit trigger to only those accountIds inserted or updated by the triggering update or insert.

or you can also can use join to accomplish same restriction.

```
  Create trigger trig_NoSingleRegId 
  On MyTable For Insert, Update
  As

        if Exists(Select * From MyTable t
                      join inserted I
                           on i.AccountId = t.AccountId
                   Group By t.AccountId   
                   Having Count(Distinct t.regularId) > 1)     
        Begin
            RollBack Transaction
            Raiserror('Cannot have more than one RegularId per AccountId', 16, 1)
        End
```

Comment: I keep getting a "missing ON keyword" error even after trying to apply a lot of adjustments to the trigger.

Comment: Sorry, I had the `On mytable`,   and the  `for Update, Insert` parts in the wrong order.